# How to trigger click for fancybox html pop in magento

Tags: jquery, magento, fancybox

I have fancybox popup in magento hrader.phtml file and the popup working fine when you click on the link. but i want to fire the fancybox with no click but according to an if statment in php code. the link of the popup working fine with the php and the popup would open.

I am not sure if the problem is the conflict jQuery & magento conflict or there is something else with fancy box.  Here is my code

```
if ($display_popup == 1) {
    echo "<br> DISPLAY POPUP";
    ?>

<a  id="inline" href="#thankyou">popup</a>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    //open_popup_auto(); 
    //jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#thankyou").fancybox().trigger('click');
        alert('working cooool');

    });

    /*$(document).ready(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            'width': '40%',
            'height': '40%',
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'type': 'iframe',
            'href': 'http://www.google.com'
        });
}); */
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you understand what is the fancybox's *trigger* and what is the fancybox's *target*.

If you have this (rendered) html (Magneto or not)

```
<a  id="inline" href="#thankyou">popup</a>
```

it means that the selector `#inline` is the *trigger* and the selector `#thankyou` is the *target*.

Then you have to bind fancybox to the ***trigger*** AND `trigger` a `click` on that selector like :

```
$("#inline").fancybox().trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question, you want to register event on the basis of php condition

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php if ($display_popup == 1) { ?>

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#thankyou").fancybox().trigger('click');
    alert('working cooool');

});

<?php }else{ ?>

    $("#thankyou").fancybox({});

<?php } ?>
```